# Split a large text file into multiple files using delimiters

Tags: python, text, split, delimiter

I would like to split a large text file into multiple text files using a delimiter like `[TEST]`, like this:

```
texttexttext
texttexttext
texttexttext
[TEST] title1
texttexttext1
texttexttext1
texttexttext1
[TEST] title2
texttexttext2
texttexttext2
texttexttext2
[TEST] title3
texttexttext3
texttexttext3
texttexttext3
```

It should be split into multiple text files:

title1.txt that contains:

```
texttexttext1
texttexttext1
texttexttext1
```

title2.txt that contains:

```
texttexttext2
texttexttext2
texttexttext2
```

title3.txt that contains:

```
texttexttext3
texttexttext3
texttexttext3
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution to read and write at the same time to avoid keeping anyting in memory could be:

```
with open('input.txt') as f:
    f_out = None
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith('[TEST]'):      # we need a new output file
            title = line.split(' ', 1)[1]
            if f_out:
                f_out.close()
            f_out = open(f'{title}.txt', 'w')
        if f_out:
            f_out.write(line)
    if f_out:
        f_out.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

As the first thing you should read the bigger `text.txt` file:

```
with open('text.txt', 'r+') as text:
    contents: list[str] = text.read().split('\n\n') # There are two newlines between the paragraphs, right?
```

And then put them into numbered files:

```
for index, element in enumerate(contents):
    with open(f'text{index}.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(element)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the delimiter is '[TEST]' not the blank between text, sorry for not precising it.